# Join Between view and three tables

Tags: sql, join

I have two view that result like as shown below and

[image]

I have lookup table for FeatureId containing also other information but here i took only required column

[image]

I have lookup table for parameter containing also other information but here i took only required column

[image]

Every featureId collects all parameters:
Question: Now I want my final resultet should list all parameter and featureId with totalcount + when have FeatureId, Parameter is not present in resultset then totalcount should be Zero

Example 
1. **ASt-1** is not at all present in resultset so there will be 10 records with featureid **ASt-1** containing all parameters with TotalCount as zero

1. **ASt-11** has one record in resultset for parameter NO2 so there will be 10 records with featureid **ASt-11** containing 9 parameters with TotalCount as zero and one Parameter i,e NO2 with value 1

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` to generate all the rows.  Then bring in the existing information using a `left join` and `group by`:

```
select f.featureid, p.parameterid, count(lu.featureid)
from (select featureid from features f) f cross join
     (select distinct parameterid from lookup) p left join
     lookup lu
     on lu.featureid = f.featureid and lu.parameterid = lu.parameterid
group by f.featureid, p.parameterid;
```